# Save image with imagepng() and file permission 664

Tags: php, linux, gd

I'm using GD to create an image. Write on it and then save it. 
Here's my code:

```
$contentPath = '/var/www/my-site/my-path/';
$font = 'someFont.ttf';

$image = imagecreatetruecolor(1280, 1024);
$white = imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 255, 255);
$black = imagecolorallocate($image, 0, 0, 0 );

imagefilledrectangle($image, 0, 0, 1280, 1024, $white);

imagettftext($image, 35, 0, 65, 750, $black, $font, 'SOME TEXT');
imageline ($image, $leftBoundingBox , 763 , 435 , 763 , $black);

imagepng($image, $contentPath);
imagedestroy($image);
```

Everything is working just fine. I need to manipulate the file later so I need to save it with a file permission of 664. Is that in anyway possible? I can't save it an then us chmod() since I have no permissions to write it form apache anymore.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: I'm not sure why if you've written the file as the apache user (and therefore it's owned by the apache user) you then can't modify the permissions of that file after you've written it? Do you get an error when you try to?

Comment: *What* needs to manipulate it later? You by downloading it over SFTP or some process running under the Apache user (possibly *www-data*)? If it's you, you'll need to sort out group privileges so that the SFTP user is in the same group as the Apache user so you can write to it with the group privileges... if it's a process under Apache there shouldn't be an issue since that created the file in the first place.

Comment: I tried to leave to owner permission to root and give the permission to write on the group. I changed the owner of the file container to www-data and it's working fine now. Thank you. 
I have to manipulate the picture after creating it with GD to apply dither and various other things.